# Chaining CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to chain two `CollectionViewSource`s in WPF application.
Is there any way to make following things work?

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace ChainingCollectionViewSource
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public IEnumerable<int> Items => Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
    public MainWindow()
    {
      DataContext = this;
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ChainingCollectionViewSource.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsViewA"
                              Source="{Binding Items}" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsViewB"
                              Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewA}}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewB}}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are trying to do this? Perhaps there is a better way to go about it?

Comment: This is basically an extract of more complex object tree. Imagine control A that filters its data via CollectionViewSource and pass it to ItemsSource of control B. It works until control B will try to do its own filtering, grouping or sorting by binding its ItemsSource to its own CollectionViewSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CollectionViewSource` doesn't filter its source collection, it filters the view. Whenever you bind to some collection of data in WPF, you are always binding to an automatically generated view and not to the actual source collection itself. A view is a class that implements the `System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView` interface and provides functionality to sort, filter, group and keeping track of the current item in a collection.

So instead of trying to "chaining" two `CollectionViewSources` together you should bind them to the same source collection:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsViewA" Source="{Binding Items}" />
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsViewB" Source="{Binding Items}" />
```

They can then filter the views independently of each other.

If you want to apply control B's filters on top of control A's filters, you should implement this logic in the `Filter` event handler of the `CollectionViewSource`, e.g.:

```
private void ItemsViewA_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Accepted = Include(e.Item as YourType);
}

private bool Include(YourType obj)
{
    //your filtering logic...
    return true;
}

private void ItemsViewB_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item as YourType;
    e.Accepted = Include(item) && /* your additional filtering logic */;
}
```

Comment: So basically there is no way to chain them because ICollectionView is not supported by Source property of CollectionViewSource.